# Concatenated formula in VBA editor not appearing

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this has been asked, can't seem to find similar questions.

I have a pretty long formula that I need to put into a cell via a macro (see below), using FormulaR1C1. I know the text string itself can fit, as i happened to omitt the first =, and the entire string of text was input into the cell. When I add it back in though, nothing appears in the desired cell.

Context: I'm trying to find that data from a column from each month's worksheet (thus there are 12), and summing that up. As for why I'm using the column function for the vlookup column, its so that i can do a fill later on.
The iferror is to make sure that if the sheet doesn't exist, the formula will still work.

Anyone able to assist me? Thanks...

```
Cells(3, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=IfError(Vlookup(rc1, Sheets(1).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(2).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(3).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(4).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(5).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(6).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(7).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(8).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(9).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(10).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(11).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)" & _
    "+ IfError(VLookup(rc1, Sheets(12).Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(8000, 60)), COLUMN(R[-2]C[32]), False), 0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing VBA code with a formula. You would not be able to `Sheets(2).range(cells(7,1))` inside of a formula. You would either need to take that part out of quotations so for example you will need to match your code to be something like `VLookup(rc1," &  Sheets(2).Range(Cells(7, 1) " &, REST OF CODE`

Or use the actual sheet reference. So it would be `VLookup(rc1, Sheet2!A7, REST OF CODE` whenever you have a VBA reference to a sheet or VBA code reference.

You would need to make sure you do this for all your code. As you cannot use the vba reference to cells or sheets in an actuall sheet formula like you have tried to do.